# Why are Excel RGB values backwards?

Tags: vba, excel, hex, rgb

This function is an example.  Note that the RGB values are actually BGR values.  Why does excel do this?

```
 Function GetRGB(ByVal cell As Range) As String

 Dim R As String, G As String
 Dim b As String, hexColor As String
 hexCode = Hex(cell.Interior.Color)

 'Note the order excel uses for hex is BGR.
 b = Val("&H" & Mid(hexCode, 1, 2))
 G = Val("&H" & Mid(hexCode, 3, 2))
 R = Val("&H" & Mid(hexCode, 5, 2))

 GetRGB = R & ":" & G & ":" & b
 End Function
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003324/how-do-i-get-the-corresponding-hex-value-of-an-rgb-color-in-excel-vba  Simply put numbers are right to left not left to right.  As to WHY microsoft did it this way... Shrug.  I'm guessing it has to do with RGB R is first so it's the first numbers on the right.  some crazy logic but as long as it's consistent... shrug.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with us (in most languages) reading text from left to right, but numbers increase from right to left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel RGB values are not backwards, actually Excel or in a broader sense, windows uses BGR color model.

Reference links:

a. [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#rgbcolor)
b. [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003324/how-do-i-get-the-corresponding-hex-value-of-an-rgb-color-in-excel-vba)
c. [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367449/bgr-color-space)

Comment: hmm.Just wanted to say that you already know what to reverse..Would not dare to refrain you from pursuing them...