# HEX color codes in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hex

Hi I am using HEX() to indicate the color of specific cells in excel. I did 4 examples and results given are confusing. 2 of 4 gave 6-digits HEX code and the other 2 gave 4-digits HEX code. I did a search online and seems like HEX code has to be 6-digits? So what do these 4-digits code stand for?

I also put these 4-digits code in https://www.color-hex.com/ and no results were found.

```
Sub showcolor()

Debug.Print Hex(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Cells(10, "AB").Interior.Color)
Debug.Print Hex(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Cells(34, "AB").Interior.Color)
Debug.Print Hex(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Cells(13, "AB").Interior.Color)
Debug.Print Hex(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Cells(12, "AB").Interior.Color)

End Sub
```

The results given are

C0FF
FFFF
F0B000
FFFFFF

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use Hex over something like RGB?

Comment: Hexadecimal values aren't "codes", they're numbers, expressed in base 16 (16 symbols) - we're used to seeing numbers in base 10 (10 symbols). You're getting 4 digit values for the same reason we don't express the value `10` as `000010`.

Comment: @dwirony      I just need to set a IF sentence so technically RGB works too, but I don't know how to find out RGB code of a cell.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon So can I understand 'C0FF' is actually '00C0FF'?

Comment: @AnctorHu exactly, yes; the number of leading zeroes is insignificant

Comment: That said IIRC there *is* something awkward about cell colors expressed in RGB - if I recall, R and B values are inverted. EDIT: [yup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003324/1188513)

Comment: All here and more!  http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you so much. However for the first one 'c0ff', if I search '00c0ff' in https://www.color-hex.com/ the color given out is light blue, whereas the real color in the cell is yellow. How does that happen?

Comment: @TimWilliams appreciate that

Comment: R=00, G=C0, B=FF would be a light blue indeed. R=FF, G=C0, B=00 would be some kind of yellow. See previous comment about R and B being reversed.

Comment: Use `Right$(Hex$(&H80000000 Or RGB((Color \ 65536) And 255, (Color \ 256) And 255, Color And 255)), 6)` to convert the color to an RGB hex string,

Answer (score 6):

The `Range.Interior.Color` property returns RGB:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color

Thus, in the `FFFF`, the first two values of the Hex() are skipped. The correct one should be `00FFFF`. This is achievable with a concatenation trick:

`Right("000000" & Hex(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "A").Interior.Color), 6)`

Furthermore, as mentioned in the comments by @Mathiew Guindon, the RGB values in VBA [are reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003324/how-do-i-get-the-corresponding-hex-value-of-an-rgb-color-in-excel-vba) (for whatever reason). Then a nice reverse back of these two is needed. This is done in the `HexToRgb()` function:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "A").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Debug.Print Hex(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "A").Interior.Color)  'FFFF
    Debug.Print Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "A").Interior.Color       '65535

    Dim hexColor As String
    hexColor = Right("000000" & Hex(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "A").Interior.Color), 6)

    Debug.Print HexToRgb(hexColor)                               'FFFF00

End Sub

Public Function HexToRgb(hexColor As String) As String

    Dim red As String
    Dim green As String
    Dim blue As String

    red = Left(hexColor, 2)
    green = Mid(hexColor, 3, 2)
    blue = Right(hexColor, 2)

    HexToRgb = blue & green & red

End Function
```

And `ffff00` is yellow - https://www.color-hex.com/color/ffff00:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading or saving the color hex code in a string i.e. `00FF00` for green,
The following VBA code segment should translate the hex color value to the VBA color value:

```
//Variables
Dim ColorName as String
Dim ColorValue as long

//Translation
ColorName='00FF00'
ColorValue=Clng("&H" & ColorName)

//Use in the Code
Me.TextBox1.BorderColor=ColorValue
```

Should work.